# CakePHP and CSRF

Tags: php, cakephp, csrf

I'm new to CakePHP and am wondering how to protect my forms from Cross Site Request Forgery, ie adding a nonce to the forms. I've set the salt in the config file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the Security component to the $components array of your controller(s):

> public $components = array('Security');

CakePHP will then automatically add a nonce to your form when you use the Form helper to create your forms.

Comment: always make sure to creat all the form elements with form helper otherwise you may get errorr "black Hole"

Answer (score 0):

you can also import the Sanitze lib for extra strong security

http://book.cakephp.org/view/153/Data-Sanitization

```
App::import('Sanitize');
$badString = ";:<script><html><   // >@@#";
echo Sanitize::paranoid($badString);
// output: scripthtml
echo Sanitize::paranoid($badString, array(' ', '@'));
// output: scripthtml    @@
```