# CakePHP Secure logout

Tags: php, cakephp

I have seen on some CakePHP websites that they have extra information on the logout e.g. `http://website.com/logout/DxcFaWlFaDOw`

Apparently this is for security reasons? Can anyone tell me more about this and how to implement it using Cake?

Comment: I can only think of it as a CSRF preventing mechanism. You basically create a token for every request and check it in the next request. This prevents that someone e.g. embeds an iFrame with your URL/logout.

Answer (score 0):

These security codes are called CSRF tokens, and they are used to prevent [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) to happen. (even though using CSRF tokens in logout links is quite pointless)

You can implement it in Cake by using the Form helper and adding:

```
public $components = array('Security');
```

in your controllers.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584420/cakephp-and-csrf)

Comment: Added that but my logout link looks the same? Although the login form does get an extra hidden input field. So how do I add this to my logout link?

Comment: As far as I know, CakePHP only implements it in forms. So you need to create your own random CSRF token (or use an auto-generated one if Cake provides it) that you will put in the PHP `Session` of the user. You will then need to put the CSRF token in your logout links manually, and check if the token equals to that of the session.

I bet there is a better way to do so...